# What "Extravagant culture" could be used as an antonym to "Spartan"?

Tags: adjectives, antonyms

"Spartan" is an adjective derived from Sparta, an ancient Greek city-state famous for its austerity. The adjective is used today to mean basic and minimal. I'm looking for an antonym, i.e. a culture that implies ornate luxury. The [antonyms I'm finding](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/spartan?s=t) are words like "opulent" or "embellished", which aren't based on a culture or place. Is there an adjective based on a culture or place that implies the opposite of Spartan?

Comment: Hi Robbie, and welcome to ELU. I've added the sort of details and research we expect to see in questions; I hope you don't mind. If you think I've butchered the intent of your question, you can simply roll back my changes. :)

Comment: What the [insert strongest expletive you know] is with the "primarily opinion based" close-votes???? Are y'all absolute idiots?

Comment: The only issue with Epicurean is the lack of originating culture and geography - people can point to the city of Sparta, where there isn't a Epicurean city... as far as I can tell.  'Sybartic' fits that bill.  But it is a very obscure word.  I also wonder about towns of the Italian renaissance... Florentine or Venetian for example.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

"Spartan" is obviously a reference to the city of Sparta; if you want an antonym that keeps the geographical atmosphere, then I think [sybaritic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sybaritic) is the word you're looking for:

- pertaining to or characteristic of a sybarite; characterized by or loving luxury or sensuous pleasure
- of, relating to, or characteristic of [Sybaris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sybaris) or its inhabitants.

> Sybaris (Ancient Greek: Σύβαρις; Italian: Sibari) was an important
>   city of Magna Graecia. It was situated on the Gulf of Taranto between
>   two rivers, the Crathis (Crati) and the Sybaris (Coscile).
>
> The city was founded in 720 BC by Achaean and Troezenian settlers.
>   Sybaris amassed great wealth thanks to its fertile land and busy port.
>   Its inhabitants became famous among the Greeks for their hedonism,
>   feasts, and excesses, to the extent that "sybarite" and "sybaritic"
>   have become bywords for opulent luxury and outrageous
>   pleasure-seeking.

Comment: Yup.  Sorry I missed this one.

Comment: Awesome answer, and I'm kicking myself for not thinking of this adjective. It's the perfect antonym for Spartan. +1 from me.

Comment: @Oldcat But you haven't deleted, 6 hours later.

Comment: And they're both Greek cities, to boot.

Comment: I think that would be the answer I'm looking for then! New word for me too - I hadn't heard the term used before this. Thank you.

Comment: I would have picked "American" as it's what first popped into my head.

Comment: Please be sure to [reference your quote](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing):
    Provide a link to the original page or answer;
    Quote only the relevant portion;
    **Provide the name of the original author** (even if it's just "Wikipedia") in order that the credit remains if the link is removed by an API.

Comment: @Blazemonger, Sybaris was in Italy, but inhabited by Greeks.

Answer (score 25):

If a Spartan eschews pleasure for the sake of pleasure, then an Epicurean pursues pleasure for the sake of pleasure.

Mind you, "Epicurean" doesn't directly reference a culture.  However, it does reference a philosophical or aesthetic bent.  "Spartan" can also reference a philosophical or aesthetic bent.

Check the general references to see whether that word suits your purpose.

Comment: It references a school; I think it would be churlish to say it doesn't match OP's requirements.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: "Epicurean" is ambiguous (at best). The Epicurean school *did* consider pleasure a good thing--but also said that pleasure was (and should be) derived primarily from living simply, and limiting desires. Epicurus himself apparently lived almost exclusively on bread and water, adding cheese on holidays. At least as originally defined, it's much closer to a synonym than an antonym for "Spartan". I think it would be quite accurate to say it's a poor fit (at best) for OP's requirements.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin The modern usage of a word often departs significantly from previous / original ones. 'Is there an adjective based on a culture or place that implies the opposite of Spartan?' is certainly fulfilled by **epicurean**: adj.
1. Devoted to the pursuit of sensual pleasure, especially to the enjoyment of good food and comfort [AHDEL: note that this is the principal (first listed) modern sense]. As at least 15 others seem to agree.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Sorry, but 10 million screaming Elvis fans can be wrong, and so can 17 voters on this web site.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin You're saying that AHDEL has got it wrong? It's certainly the sense that's uppermost in my mind. Or are you saying that we should **only** use earliest [known, I assume] senses for a word? That only you can decide these things? What do we have to call a Caesarian section?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I'm saying misusing a word this badly makes you sound foolish to anybody who knows its history. You (and the OP, of course) are obviously free to do do as you wish.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin Using a word as it is defined by a dictionary as respected as AHDEL is 'misusing' it? You're proclaiming the **etymological fallacy**. [From Wikipedia](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215223/what-extravagant-culture-could-be-used-as-an-antonym-to-spartan/215229?noredirect=1#comment458546_215229):
The etymological fallacy is a genetic fallacy that holds, erroneously, that the present-day meaning of a word or phrase should necessarily be similar to its historical meaning. // I'll go with authorities other than yourself when deciding on who sounds foolish.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What is *popular* is not always what is *right*.

Comment: @snotwaffle Of course not. But one has to have a much better reason than personal preference to claim that, when it comes to English usage, the majority have got it wrong. I'm waiting to see an authority quoted by prescriptivists saying 'the present-day meaning of a word or phrase **must** necessarily be similar to its historical meaning'. I'll opt for AHDEL and its corpus studies, and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy) and its linked references, rather than Jerry Coffin and snot waffle.

Comment: as a side note, Epicurean is usually used to oppose Stoic

Comment: @njzk2 It doesn't mean it's incorrect ;-)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: no, I just wanted to point this out as it is an important part of understanding what Epicurean is to know what it is usually compared to.

Comment: @njzk2 It was intended as a joke. I'm glad someone else on this thread seems to consider the usage acceptable. And since oerkelens won't oblige, I'll post his comment showing how untenable many prescriptivist arguments in semantics are:  'I wonder how many people go around with outdated dictionaries shouting that the word _mouse_ can not be used for an electronic device because their dictionary [only] says it's an animal.' –  oerkelens

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, JerryCoffin: a few words about etymological fallacy: http://unabridged.merriam-webster.com/blog/2014/08/quest-post-the-lord-the-bishop-and-the-harlot-an-etymological-fallacy/

Answer (score 7):

*Hedonistic* fits the bill I think.

*Decadent* is slightly more oblique, but it might serve.

*Epicurean* is also a great adjective, but that's already been proposed in another answer.

Comment: The duplicate is the only answer fitting OP's request:' What “Extravagant culture” could be used as an antonym to “Spartan”?'

Answer (score 7):

Maybe [Byzantine](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Byzantine) would match your need. It is related in culture and can mean complex and intricate in contrast to simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 7):

Corinthian also fits really well.

They were known for the drunkenness and sexual excess.

Comment: These days, the only thing I know them for is their columns.... I don't think calling someone "Corinthian" would be understood as meaning that they are a pleasure-seeking, self-indulgent type.

Comment: Well this one's going to be controversial.

Comment: Can you provide a reputable source for this allegation?

Comment: The "Corinthian set" of Regency England were the jocks of the age, known for their skill at sports (under which you should think of boxing, hunting, and carriage-racing, not anything involving a ball). Other than the columns, that's the only association I have with the word "Corinthian".

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=gOemLnGyylUC&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=not+everybody+can+afford+a+trip+to+corinth&source=bl&ots=1TnB7sso6h&sig=4SdKete5NnxFGovxUYc4Tj8cGC0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NvuSVKTvLMOlNs6fgvAN&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=not%20everybody%20can%20afford%20a%20trip%20to%20corinth&f=false

Comment: That took 30 seconds. Its easy to find if you already know it is true.

Comment: There is a difference between a culture have been the opposite of Spartan and it being a useful adjective. Epicurus was actually not what we think of as a hedonist, _but_ "Epicurean" -although historically inaccurate- is a useful adjective what the OP is looking for. You have the opposite case: historically valid, but not generally known.

Comment: @ArtB "Corinthian" is moderately famous for (i.e. synonymous with) its [ornate columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corinthian_order), even if its [temple hetairas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prostitution_in_ancient_Greece#Temple_prostitution_in_Corinth) are only "generally known" to people who know a bit of the cultural stereotypes of Classical Greece.

Comment: I guess it depends on your audience but "people who know a bit of the cultural stereotypes of Classical Greece", whereas my answer "baroque" is used as a joke in Disney's "Beauty & the Beast".

Answer (score 4):

"Baroque"

Baroque was a highly decorative art style \ movement that was definitely not spartan. Specifically ["late baroque" or "rococo"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rococo).

> Rococo artists and architects used a more jocular, florid, and graceful approach to the Baroque. Their style was ornate and used light colours, asymmetrical designs, curves, and gold.

Answer (score 1):

The term [Bourgeois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourgeoisie) comes to mind:

From Wikipedia:

> In political economy, political philosophy, sociology, social sciences, and history, the bourgeoisie is the wealthy stratum of the middle class that originated during the latter part of the Middle Ages (AD 476–1453).

Answer (score -1):

**"Sybaritic"** - fond of sensuous luxury or pleasure; self-indulgent. (Google Dictionary)

Answer (score -1):

Las Vegan as in Las Vegas which is the epitome of indulgence and excess.

Answer (score -2):

How about "The Court of Louis XIV".  Pretty much defines opulence and extravagance.

Comment: +1. You could even put some geography on it and say Versallean (or whatever the proper French adjective form is for a city).